# How to start a thread running Ruby in a macOS App

Tags: swift, ruby, macos

How to start and keep an interactable Ruby thread in a macOS app?

I'm writing a macOS app using Swift which frequently needs to call a Ruby module to parse a DSL (domain specific language) Ruby file to read some attributes.

It's hard to write and maintain a ruby AST parser in Swift to read that DSL on my own.

For performance issues, I don't want to use Swift `Process()` to run a ruby shell script and read the output.

So I'm trying to create a background thread (or process) that loads and keeps the Ruby interpreter waiting for messages to execute the commands and return the results.

How to start and keep an interactable Ruby thread in a macOS app?

Comment: What is an "interactable thread?"

Comment: It sounds like you want a Ruby background process that you can communicate with using some sort of IPC method. An easy way to do this is to launch it as a server process and use TCP and/or a UNIX socket to communicate with it.

Comment: Jesse Storimer has a good blog piece entitled [Introduction to IPC in Ruby](https://www.jstorimer.com/blogs/workingwithcode/7766091-introduction-to-ipc-in-ruby) that may help you get started.